# How to change form textbox value in Zend form annotation?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, annotations

I have following Annotation exmaple. I need to change form value in zend controller

```
/** 
* @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
* @Annotation\Name("LoginForm")
* 
*/
class User
{
    /** Some comment to make this annotation work
    * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
    * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
    * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
    * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Firstname: "})
    * @Annotation\Attributes({"id":"FirstnameId"})
    */
    public $username;
```

So in controller I have:

```
$user       = new User();  
$builder    = new AnnotationBuilder();  
$this->form = $builder->createForm($user);
```

Now how can I set or change the value of User field here?
I tried `$this->form->getElement('Firstname')->setValue('FRANK');`

But it didn't work?

Comment: Ok I found my answer:  $this->form->get('Firstname')->setValue('FRANK');

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format it better and remove some clutter, but it's not clear what you're asking. Please add more explanation of what you expected and what didn't work.